# How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row

if add row to `DataTable`

```
DataRow row = datatable1.NewRow();
row["column2"]="column2";
row["column6"]="column6";
datatable1.Rows.Add(row);
```

How about `DataGridView`??

Comment: You can add the data of a datatable to a datagridview just by setting the datasource of the gridview equal to the datatable `datagridview1.DataSource = yourDataTable`

Answer (score 297, accepted):

You can do:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

or:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Another way:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five", "six", "seven","eight");
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, "one", "two", "three", "four");
```

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

Comment: thank you, if my datagridview have no rows, how can i add row?

Comment: @DavidYeung well in that case answer from MGA can help you out, what is your data source ? is it a datatable? if so you can add the row to the datatable and then refresh the data source

Comment: You cannot directly reference a column by name as you did: row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ"; ... You have to look up the index first: row.Cells[yourDataGridView.Columns["Column2"].Index].Value = "XYZ";

Comment: Ideally, you should clone the `RowTemplate` of the `DataGridView`. This becomes more of an issue when you have different styles across different rows in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: when it bided to data it will get error.

Answer (score 65):

Like this:

```
var index = dgv.Rows.Add();
dgv.Rows[index].Cells["Column1"].Value = "Column1";
dgv.Rows[index].Cells["Column2"].Value = 5.6;
//....
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well if you have a simple single column DataGridView for simple editable lists of text.

Comment: Its works great in the case when you have no data source assigned to grid view

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: And **can be easily cleared** (in case of showing new result/refreshing search data etc.) with **`datagridview1.Rows.Clear();`**

Answer (score 57):

Lets say you have a datagridview that is not bound to a dataset and you want to programmatically populate new rows...

Here's how you do it.

```
// Create a new row first as it will include the columns you've created at design-time.

int rowId = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

// Grab the new row!
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowId];

// Add the data
row.Cells["Column1"].Value = "Value1";
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "Value2";

// And that's it! Quick and painless... :o)
```

Answer (score 36):

Like this:

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "column2";
 dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "column6";

 string[] row1 = new string[] { "column2 value", "column6 value" };
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
```

Or you need to set there values individually use the propery [`.Rows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx), like this:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "cell value";
```

Comment: thank you. if the datagridview have 30 columns, but i just want to add the value to column2 and column6 and the rest keep null or empty . how can i do this??

Comment: @DavidYeung, Sure you can: `dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "cell value"`;

Comment: dataGridView.Rows.Add(null, 2, null, null, null, 6);

Comment: int addedRowIndex = dataGridViewRows.Add(); var addedRow = dataGridViewRows[addedRowIndex]; now all values are filled with the default value, you only have to change the cells that are not default: addedRow.Cells[column2.Index].Value = myValue; (assuming column2 is a DataGridViewColumn)

Answer (score 29):

Adding a new row in a DGV with no rows with **Add()** raises *SelectionChanged* event before you can insert any data (or bind an object in Tag property).

Create a clone row from **RowTemplate** is safer imho:

```
//assuming that you created columns (via code or designer) in myDGV
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow) myDGV.RowTemplate.Clone();
row.CreateCells(myDGV, "cell1", "cell2", "cell3");

myDGV.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Clone() method returned a row but with no Cells. row.Cells.Count is 0.

Comment: Markand: Call DataGridViewRow.CreateCells to initialize your Cells collection.

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Answer (score 16):

This is how I add a row if the dgrview is empty: (myDataGridView has two columns in my example)

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.CreateCells(myDataGridView);

row.Cells[0].Value = "some value";
row.Cells[1].Value = "next columns value";

myDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

According to docs: "CreateCells() clears the existing cells and sets their template according to the supplied DataGridView template".

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Answer (score 8):

If the grid is bound against a DataSet / table its better to use a BindingSource like

```
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
grid.DataSource = bindingSource;

//Add data to dataTable and then call

bindingSource.ResetBindings(false)
```

Answer (score 7):

here is another way to do such

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Age";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "City";

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("kathir", "25", "salem");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("vino", "24", "attur");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("maruthi", "26", "dharmapuri");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("arun", "27", "chennai"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to manipulate anything aside from the Cell Value string such as adding a Tag, try this:

```
DataGridViewRow newRow = (DataGridViewRow)mappingDataGridView.RowTemplate.Clone();
newRow.CreateCells(mappingDataGridView);

newRow.Cells[0].Value = mapping.Key;
newRow.Cells[1].Value = ((BusinessObject)mapping.Value).Name;
newRow.Cells[1].Tag = mapping.Value;

mappingDataGridView.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourDGV.Rows.Add(column1,column2...columnx); //add a row to a dataGridview
yourDGV.Rows[rowindex].Cells[Cell/Columnindex].value = yourvalue; //edit the value
```

you can also create a new row and then add it to the DataGridView like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.Cells[Cell/Columnindex].Value = yourvalue;
yourDGV.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone wanted to Add DataTable as a source of gridview then--

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column1"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column2"));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "column1 Value";
dr[1] = "column2 Value";

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way to do is invoking the DataGridView and using a lambda expression.  Simple one liner while also keeping the code thread safe:

```
MyDataGridView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(param1, param2, paramX)));
```

Comment: Underrated approach to populating datagridviews!

Comment: If we have columns added earlier, then this is a very quick and easy approach to add Rows.

Answer (score 1):

An example of copy row from dataGridView and added a new row in The same dataGridView:

```
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
Dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
Dt.Columns.Add("Column2");

DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
DataGridViewRow dgvR = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
dr[0] = dgvR.Cells[0].Value; 
dr[1] = dgvR.Cells[1].Value;              

Dt.Rows.Add(dR);
dataGridView1.DataSource = Dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Windows Application and using Button Click Event put this code in it.

```
dataGridView1.Rows
                .Add(new object[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add a list of BBDD
var item = myEntities.getList().ToList();
//Insert a new object of type in a position of the list       
item.Insert(0,(new Model.getList_Result { id = 0, name = "Coca Cola" }));

//List assigned to DataGridView
dgList.DataSource = item;
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it would resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you´ve already defined a `DataSource`, You can get the `DataGridView`´s `DataSource` and cast it as a `Datatable`.

Then add a new `DataRow` and set the Fields Values.

Add the new row to the `DataTable` and Accept the changes.

In C# it would be something like this..

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource;
DataRow drToAdd = dataTable.NewRow();

drToAdd["Field1"] = "Value1";
drToAdd["Field2"] = "Value2";

dataTable.Rows.Add(drToAdd);
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//header
dataGridView1.RowCount = 50;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Product_ID0";


//add row by cell 
 dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "cell value";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this useful more than once when the DataGrid is bound to a table.

```
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvData.DataSource;
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (var something in something)
        {
           row["ColumnName"] = something ;               
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        dgvData.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] splited = t.Split('>');
int index = dgv_customers.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
dgv_customers.Rows[index].Cells["cust_id"].Value=splited.WhichIsType("id;");
```

But be aware, `WhichIsType` is the extension method I created.

Comment: When you answer a question with some code, and that code requires a custom extension method you created, and you didn't include the code for the custom method, it isn't a terribly useful answer.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i am sory becuse of that. but that methode its not an important methode