# Adding rows on datagridview manually

Tags: c#, winforms

I've inserted a checkbox column and textbox column on the datagridview.
how can add rows manually on the textbox column.

It should be like this:

```
checkbox | textbox
............................
checkbox | item1
checkbox | item2
checkbox | item3
checkbox | item4
```

Here is the code for checkbox and textbox on datagridview

```
public void loadgrid()
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    checkboxColumn.Width = 25;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkboxColumn);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textboxcolumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    textboxcolumn.Width = 150;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(textboxcolumn);     
}
```

Comment: Your references to `chk` and `txt` objects aren't doing anything in this code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass an object array that contains the values which should be inserted into the `DataGridView` in the order how the columns are added. For instance you could use this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { true, "string1" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { false, "string2" });
```

And you can build object array from whatever you want, just be sure to match the type (i.e. use bool for checkedColumn)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Rows collection to manually populate a DataGridView control instead of binding it to a data source.

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five", "six", "seven", "eight");
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, "one", "two", "three", "four");
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx)

And you can do something like this too:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063825/395659)