# Show 2d-array in DataGridView

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I have a 2D array.  I want to print the array in my `DataGridView` but it throws an error:

> [Argument OutOfRangeException was unhandled ]

This is my code

```
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
            dataGridView1[i, j].Value = state[i, j].h;    
            //state[i, j].h this is my array 
            dataGridView1[i, j].Style.BackColor pixelcolor[i,j];
            dataGridView1[i, j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is looking for an array of DataGridViews.  You probably want to target the rows and cells.

Comment: You should add rows, like in this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362971/adding-rows-on-datagridview-manually

Comment: I use   
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                    {  
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {true,state[i,j].h});
                       
                    }    but I have this error   InvalidOperationException was unhandle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As comments have pointed out, you should focus on rows and cells.  You need to build your `DataGridView` columns and then populate each row cell by cell.

The `width` of your array should correspond to your dgv columns and the `height` to the dgv rows.  Take the following as a simple example:

```
string[,] twoD = new string[,]
{
  {"row 0 col 0", "row 0 col 1", "row 0 col 2"},
  {"row 1 col 0", "row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2"},
  {"row 2 col 0", "row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2"},
  {"row 3 col 0", "row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2"},
};

int height = twoD.GetLength(0);
int width = twoD.GetLength(1);

this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount = width;

for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
  row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);

  for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
  {
    row.Cells[c].Value = twoD[r, c];
  }

  this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: I have question please how can I make each cell be smaller

Comment: @lenalena A good way is to play with the value of `AutoSizeColumnsMode`.  For example, if you want all columns to fit the largest displayed text per column, do this:  `this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;`

Comment: @lenalena Similarly, you could also change such for individual columns: `dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;`  Conversely, you could just manually set the width: `dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 50;`

Comment: and the height how can resize it like this or out  dataGridView1.Rows[1].Height = 80;

Answer (score 1):

for exemple for 2 elements

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
var dataArray = new int[] { 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Count; i++)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, dataArray[i] });
}
```

Comment: if I have 2D array ??

Answer (score 0):

The first potential problem is with how you are accessing your array indexes. Which can be handled this way.

```
string[,] a = {
  {"0", "1", "2"},
      {"0", "1", "2"},
      {"0", "1", "2"},
      {"0", "1", "2"},
  };

for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a[i,j]);
    }
}
```

Just check your array dimension length first. Clearly one of your variables height or width is incorrect.

This is done using     `Array.GetLength(int dimension)`

The second problem is how you are adding items to your datagridview.

Comment: The answer is completely unrelated with the question!