# Populating a datagridview from a list through event

Tags: c#, list, events, datagridview

Okay, so I'm doing my first assessment/task in my programming course, so keep in mind I'm very new to this.

So I've got a CSV file with a list of products with stock amounts, name, code and OnOrder properties, and I've done what I think is the first big step of writing the program to take said list and put it in the program into a DataGridView (this is all freeform but I have to firstly use a list or array, and secondly must have sorting by either item code or count etc).

here's my code so far:

```
namespace SkillageAppForm
{
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        args = new[] { "C:\\StockFile\\stocklist.csv" };

        var dailyvalues = ReadValues(args[0]);
    }

    public class DailyValues
    {
        public string ItemCode;
        public string ItemDescription;
        public int CurrentCount;
        public string OnOrder;

        public static DailyValues FromLine(string line)
        {
            var data = line.Split(',');

            return new DailyValues()
            {
                ItemCode = data[0],
                ItemDescription = data[1],
                CurrentCount = int.Parse(data[2]),
                OnOrder = data[3]
            };
        }
    }

    public IList<DailyValues> ReadValues(string path)
    {
        var myList = new List<DailyValues>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1))
        {
            myList.Add(DailyValues.FromLine(line));
        }
        return myList;
    }
}
```

so, running this and setting a break point, it seems to populate myList just like I want it to, so yay. But now I'm super confused as to how to get that list into the DataGridView, the way I've tried so far is just by using a click event to load it into the DataGridView using datasource (I'm assuming therefore that you can't actually call a list from eventhandlers, but googling this issue just comes up with random OTHER things like calling events in methods and making a list within the event handler).

I just have no idea how to do this, as I said I'm super new to coding and while I've watched like 40 hours of Pluralsight courses, I'm still really confused heh.

I'm assuming there's some simple mistake I made or giant thing I'm missing, and I'm not here to cheat my assessment, just because I've been sitting here for several hours trying to figure this out on google and looking back through classes and can't actually find an answer. Thanks so much for any help anyway :)

Comment: You need to find a tutorial.  SO is not a code writing service.  But this might help you to determine how to insert manually:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362971/adding-rows-on-datagridview-manually

Comment: What @jason.kaisersmith said, plus, if your DataGridView is on Form1, you are reading the file *after* the form has been shown, so unless you want to pass the list in to populate the grid afterwards, you would be better served reading the file from the form code-behind. Or reading it before opening the form, and passing the list to the form through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easier, sack off the custom class entirely and load the data into a suitably prepared DataTable instead (i.e. make a DataTable, add relevant named and typed columns to it, load it with rows) and then set the .DataSource of the DataGridView to be the datatable.

Ensure `AutoGenerateColumns = true` on the DataGridView