# not able to see the all the rows except the last

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

```
while (dr2.Read())
        {               
            dataGridViewEx1["Sno", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount-1].Value = sno;
            dataGridViewEx1["Prod_Code", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount-1].Value = dr2["Code"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1["Description", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount-1 ].Value = dr2["Desc"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1["Qty", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount-1 ].Value = 0;
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridViewEx1.Rows[dataGridViewEx1.RowCount - 1].Cells["UOM"];
            cell.Value = dr2["UOM1"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1["OnHand", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount - 1].Value = dr2["Weight"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1["uom1", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount - 1].Value = dr2["UOM"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1["UPrice", dataGridViewEx1.RowCount - 1].Value = dr2["Price"].ToString();
            dataGridViewEx1.Rows.Add(1);
            //dataGridViewEx1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

        }
        dr2.Close();
```

This Code only adding last row. why it's not adding the previous rows .....i even tested with the commitedit but no use ..

Comment: [c# How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.but my requirement is different it should not effect the datagridview comboBox column ............

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting  everytime only to the raw: `dataGridViewEx1.RowCount-1`

Comment: but i am changing the row count every time