# Datagridviewrow using column name instead of index

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Here is the code I'm using below

```
Dim lname As New DataGridViewColumn

lname.Name = "LastName"
lname.DataPropertyName = "LastName"
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(lname)

Dim itrow = New DataGridViewRow    
itrow.CreateCells(DataGridView1)                
itrow.Cells(0).Value = empcoll.Item(i).LastName <<works
itrow.Cells("LastName").Value = empcoll.Item(i).LastName <<error column name can't be found
```

I'm having trouble with using `datagridviewrow.cells("column name")`. Can anyone enlighten or help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it is to add a row check out this answer. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically>

Comment: I'm trying to add columns and rows to the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I slightly change something to try the code if it works):

```
  Dim lname As New DataGridViewColumn
  lname.Name = "LastName"
  lname.DataPropertyName = "LastName"
  lname.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell 'I had to add this to my code

  DataGridView1.Columns.Add(lname)

  Dim itrow As New DataGridViewRow
  itrow = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.Rows.Add())
  itrow.Cells("LastName").Value = "Give here your Value"
```

Comment: thanks habouf! your code works. So I really have to add .cellTemplate for every column that I will add. Thanks again!

Comment: You can also create do "Dim lname as New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn" which takes care of that for you.

Comment: WozzeC- sure I'll try that one as well thanks!

one question is there any alternative for 
itrow=datagridview1.rows(datagridview1.rows.add())?

Comment: Sure , it depends what you are trying to achieve.