# Displaying data from datagridview to textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    //gets a collection that contains all the rows
    DataGridViewRow row = this.tbl_deliveryDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    //populate the textbox from specific value of the coordinates of column and row. 
    noTextBox.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    supplierTextBox.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    invoiceNumberTextBox.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    dRNumberTextBox.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    pONumberTextBox.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Is it possible to change the numbers inside the bracket into column name? How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datagridviewrow using column name instead of index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583687/datagridviewrow-using-column-name-instead-of-index)

Comment: `row.Cells["YourColumnName"]`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel there's an error, here: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Column named Supplier cannot be found." 

how come the column name cannot be found? i correct is thrice if the spelling is correct, and it is. how come?

Comment: You need to post more code to answer this question. How do you populate column? DataBound and auto generated columns? Or manually done? Show those code please

Comment: @user3875997 are you sure that **Supplier** is a value of [**Name**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name.aspx)  property of your column? I assume that Supplier is a value of [**HeaderText**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx) property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is that the connection string?

Comment: @IvanZub I see. Thanks! I thought, i will just follow what's name of the column.

Comment: May be you are getting the exception because you are missing the *.Value.ToString();* from Sriram's suggestion.  So it should look like this:     row.Cells["ColName1"].Value.ToString()