# Add a last row manually to datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I want to add a rows to my datagridview after its fetch the data from the database.
For example :

```
Product - - - Price
   1    - - - 100
   2    - - - 100
   3    - - - 100
 Total  - - - 300
```

The Total is the value I would add manually. Any help thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Add a label for sum in your FooterTemplate

and on server side in rowdatabound event,

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
   //Do your code
    }
    }
```