# How to add a row to a DataGridView bound to a data table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a data table.  I would like to add a row just to the DataGridView and not to the data source so that I can show the sum of a specific field in the last row of the grid.   Is this possible with the DataGridView?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: AFAIK not possible, you've to add row to `DataTable` only. I may be wrong

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: you could place a label in the footer of the grid and sum you column and place the value there.