# want to add data into dataGridview from C# code

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have some data and I want to add to data Grid View.I want enter data from C# program-me code.I don't want to send them into database.When i enter some name from code I should appear in data Grid view.How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Comment: My question is very simple.when i run my  project i can display Massage boxes from MessageBox.Show(print.Name+":"+print.PrinterStatus.ToString()+":"+print.PrinterStatus+":"+print.Shared); .    
Now I want appear those data in datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like, following code would set the value to row 0 and column 0. If you want to set the value to different cell then adjust the Row and Cell index.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "some value";
```

Comment: worked that's wt I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new row with data to your DataGridView:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: @user3027412 Why my answer is not the correct one anymore?