# cellendedit event in gridview add row in another gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

have 2 DataGridview 
and Cellendedit event in first one 
how i can  make this event add row in the second DataGridview   ?

```
 DataGridViewTextBoxCell textBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                                textBoxCell.Value = itemDetails.First().UnitNameArabic;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = itemDetails.First().SalePrice;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = itemDetails.First().NameArabic;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = itemDetails.First().Number;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] = textBoxCell;
                                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                                row.Cells[0].Value = itemDetails.First().NameArabic;
                                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
                                dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

Not working with second GridView

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/c-sharp-how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: in `dataGridView1_CellEndEdit` event add row in second datagridview is wrok correctly. what kind of error you get it

Comment: Your code should work fine. There must be something else interrupting. You don't need the `Refresh()` call. Please provide more relevant code.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting an error or exception?

Comment: no , nothing effect in grideview2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataGridViewRow row2 = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Clone();
```