# adding multiple items one by one in datagridview in c# window form

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

```
private void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in ProductAddGridView.Rows)
    {
        dgvr.Cells[0].Value = productIDTextBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[1].Value = productTypeIDComboBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[2].Value = companyIDComboBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[3].Value = productPurchaseRateTextBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[4].Value = productQtyTextBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[5].Value = productDescriptionRichTextBox.Text;
        dgvr.Cells[6].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(productQtyTextBox.Text.Trim()) * Convert.ToDecimal(productPurchaseRateTextBox.Text));
     }
}
```

I am trying to add multiple products one by one in a datagridview before saving it to database. But whenever I add a row in datagridview second time, the first row gets replaced by the second row -- it only works for single row addition.

Comment: You're not actually adding any rows...

Comment: whenever i click save button,1 row appear in datagridview,m not adding it in database,i m retrieving values from textboxes,combos,n want to display it in datagridview.

Comment: If you are trying to add a new product then you must add new DataGridViewRow everytime to datagridview. Here, you are looping through rows which is not required.

Comment: @Vishki What is `ProductAddGridView`? Where do you initialise it? Your `foreach` statement will go through the **existing rows** and change the values.

Comment: ProductAddGridView is a gridview to show added products to list.it is like a cart for user,user should br able to add new products one by one in his list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly getting what are you looking for but if you want to add multiple row in to your datagrid view you will need to create a data row and then you can add that row in datagrid.
You can refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063825/2794391)