# How to use BindingSource DataSource with a list of DataGridViewRow?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a DataGridView using Binding Source. The problem is that I don't know how to pass a list of DataGridViewRow (or any kind of structure, except DataTable that I'm avoiding at the moment) to the BindingSource DataSource, because by doing this I see all the class properties instead of Cells content only. This code doesn't seem to work:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = dgvRowsList;
bindingSource.DataMember = "Cells";
datagrid.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewRows are generated automatically as a result of databinding b/w datagridview and datasource object which is usually some .net data structure like List, DataTable, etc. You probably don't need to use databinding, rather manipulate datagridview directly, this way you will be creating new rows manually. Please see [How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically).

If you for some reason want to have control on how databinding interpret the data in datasource object, you need to define your custom TypeDescriptor that returns PropertyDescriptor collection, and by doing this you can specify what will be exposed as properties of underlying data object (but this solution is rather for complex cases).

Comment: Initially I was using AddRows method, passing a list of DataGridViewRow. It works flawless. But now I need to use DataBinding, so I'm lost.

TypeDescriptor seems too much complex, as you've already mentioned. I'll wait for a simpler solution. Thanks anyway. :)