# Winforms DatagridView Columns Headers text throw error : index out of range

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, header

I create a datagridview with 6 columns in my winform.
I populate it by adding rows :

```
var items = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach (object o in objs)
{
        var item = new DataGridViewRow();
    /*
     * define content of each cell c1 to c6
     * 
     */

        item.Cells.Add(c1);
        item.Cells.Add(c2);
        item.Cells.Add(c3);
        item.Cells.Add(c4);
        item.Cells.Add(c5);
        item.Cells.Add(c6);

        items.Add(item);
    
}
gridviewObjs.Rows.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

When I tried to define headers of these 6 columns I got error :

> Index out of range.

I can add headers for only the three first columns without throwing this exception.

```
gridviewObjs.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Id";
gridviewObjs.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Full Name";
gridviewObjs.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Type";
//gridviewObjs.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Age";
//gridviewObjs.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Range";
//gridviewObjs.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Start Date";
```

If I try to uncomment the 4th column header text line I got the exception.

I have the same problem when I call the column directly

> gvcAge.HeaderText = "Age";

So, did anyone has an idea about how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: [Probably this question/answer will trigger the light](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically). A DataGridViewRow unrelated to any DataGridVIew has no way to know how many columns you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(DataGridView).Columns.Add` to add columns and specific their headers:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column1Name", "Column 1 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column2Name", "Column 2 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column3Name", "Column 3 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column4Name", "Column 4 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column5Name", "Column 5 Header");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column6Name", "Column 6 Header");
```