# How to add dynamically row in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#

How can I dynamically add a row in `datagridview` in c#. Sum of cell and print total answer in the last row?

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Please take a look at this? [add row to datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically); maybe post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You want a footer row if I am correct. You must add a

```
<FooterTemplate> </FooterTemplate>
```

in your data grid. Then you can use it in RowCreated, Page Unload events (or where you need) to modify contents and display desired data.

You could use RowCreated event as :

```
protected void MyGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            //e.Row.FindControl("what ever control i have");
            //use the control to modify content
        }
    }
```