# Confused with Visual Studios DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a DataGridView in C# and i am able to edit what is in it while the program is active but i am wondering how to add data to it programmatically. This way when the program starts i can already have data in their. By the way, this is all using windows forms. Thanks!

~I am getting data from a flat text file. if you don't know what this is it is basically using a text file as a database in a more sloppy way. So for each line of data coming in from the text file, i want to split up the line and put it into a DataGridView.

Comment: Data? What data? Where do you get this initial data? From a database, from a file, manually defined? Add more context please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: If you're confused, imagine how we feel.

Comment: You can put data in a `BindingList<T>` or a `DataTable` and the assign it to `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. You can fill the `BindingList<T>` or `DataTable` from database or manually add items to them in `Load` event of form.

Comment: @Steve answered your question.

Comment: Add also an example of content of text file.

Comment: @JimHewitt thanks so much for the answer! Exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use data binding, this pattern works well

```
string[] row = new string[numColumns];
List<string> lines;
// Add code here to read and parse your file
// Each file line is added to lines
  foreach (var line in lines)
  {
        // Split the line into fields, tab assumed here
        string[] fields= line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
        // Add validation of file contents
        row[0] = fields[0];
        row[1] = fields[1];
        // etc.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```