# Adding new data in a row VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Instead of adding data in the new blank row, it creates a blank row and adds new data in the add new '*'. Like this:

[image]

`Vdroptable` as the datagridview
Here's the code of delete row

```
If Vdroptable.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString = "A1B1" Then
    Vdroptable.Rows(j).Selected = True
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Vdroptable.SelectedRows
        Vdroptable.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next
```

Code of adding row

```
If SpanName.Text = "A1B1" Then
    iVdroptable.Rows.Add()
            Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = "A1B1"
            Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = "A1"
            Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = "B1"
```

Comment: I have two buttons, input and delete. Whenever I delete for eg. 'A1B1' then add it again... i always come up with the picture above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Comment: I actually assume that there's a question resembles this but I think that possible duplicate did not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You have no parameter inside the `Add()` therefore it is empty. You need to pass values to it, like this:

```
iVdropTable.Rows.Add("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
```

This should fix the inserting part, which is the question about. If you want to solve the deleting part here as well, you will need to elaborate the problem you have.

Comment: but the table is incrementing... after the code `iVdroptable.Rows.Add()` I added:
                `Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = "A1B1"
                Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = "A1"
                Vdroptable.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = "B1"`

Comment: @isshi, can you show us what we the exact input and what were the exact operations you did, what did you expect and what did you get instead.

Comment: I already posted the result (in the photo attached in my question)