# C#: Adding DataGridViewRow to DataGridView Exception

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I've been trying to add a DataGridViewRow to a DataGridView to no avail. I followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically). I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code!

I'd like to add data using *associative* keys and not indices :

```
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
```

This is my code:

```
DataGridViewRow dgvr = (dgvSponsor.RowTemplate);
        dgvr.Cells["firstName"].Value = fn;
        dgvr.Cells["midName"].Value = mi;
        dgvr.Cells["lastName"].Value = ln;
        dgvr.Cells["suffix"].Value = suffix;
        dgvr.Cells["residence"].Value = res;
        dgvr.Cells["gender"].Value = radioMale.Checked ? 1 : 2;
```

I'm getting an **`ArgumentException`**:
[image]

I've already set the names for the columns like so:
[image]

Why is it still throwing an Exception?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to add data, but the way I mostly use is to create the row and then add the data as follows;

```
//Insert a new row, get the index of that row
int index =  myDataGridView.Rows.Add();

//Now add the data into the row you just created
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["firstName"].Value = fn;
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["midName"].Value = mi;
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["lastName"].Value = ln;
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["suffix"].Value = suffix;
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["residence"].Value = res;
myDataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["gender"].Value = radioMale.Checked ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try set DataPropertyName to firstName and all other columns in a row should be set accordingly.