# How can i add a new empty row in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I want to add a new row with empty cells, but I don't know the number of columns (variable) in the DataGridView. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily using following code. The markup below is for a page with gridview and C# code below is for button click event that adds an empty row without any specific knowledge of the names or datatypes of columns.

This is tried and tested.

**C# code for button click to add a new empty row**

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row1 = GridView1.Rows[0];
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    for (int i = 0; i < row1.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        Table parentTable = row1.Parent as Table;
        parentTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

**aspx Markup with gridview**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GridViewSample.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewSample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Add Row" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [QuantityPerUnit], [UnitPrice], [UnitsInStock], [UnitsOnOrder], [CategoryName] FROM [Alphabetical list of products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```