# add new row to datagridview programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to add new row to datagridview ,I try by using this code

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dgv_OfferTerms.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = cond.Id;
row.Cells[1].Value = cond.Name;
row.Cells[2].Value = cond.Title;
row.Cells[3].Value = cond.Description;
dgv_OfferTerms.Rows.Add(row);
```

it didn't work so i try this

```
dgv_OfferTerms.Rows.Add(cond.Id,cond.Name,cond.Title,cond.Description);
```

didn't work 
how can i add new row to datagridview??

Comment: Most of the time you will want to add rows to the datasource not the control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new row to datagridview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)

Comment: @Jimi I try this answer but it didn't work with me

Comment: @Abd ul rahaman Shalata  Why? What happens when you add the new row? Are you sure you are feeding the right fields and field format?

Answer (score 4):

These code may help you:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five", "six", "seven","eight");
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, "one", "two", "three", "four");
```

or:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Reference from:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx

Comment: It works fine with me. Must make sure to declare Bound Column Properties. In my case I created two columns which are ***`Name`***, ***`Address`***. Now on your button click event add this sample code ***`this.datagridview1.Rows.Add("nameTest","addressTest");`***, After this code executes, This must work.

Comment: to elaborate the data in datagridview1, iterate over the datagridview1.Rows:              foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { ...  }