# How to solve adding row into datagridview with existing columns?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying my first project using linq query. I stuff on adding new row into datagridview which is already existed column names.

Actually, it can be done by

```
grid.DataSource = qry.ToList();
```

but due to some reasons of unicode character for column `HeaderText`. Thus I will get only each row into the DataGridView with existing column names.

I need to display the `HeaderText` with local language. However, I can change the `HeaderText` in several way as need but base on experience I think designing `HeaderText` in UI site is the best way for me.

Below is some code I had practiced.

```
var qry = (from c in db.TBLCOMPANY 
           where (c.STATUSFLAG == 1) 
           select c).OrderByDescending(c => c.LASTUPDATE);
// grid.DataSource = qry.ToList();

int i = 0;

foreach (MCOMPANY item in qry.ToList())
{
    i = +1;

    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();

    dr.Cells[0].Value = item.OID.ToString();// Error start from this line
    dr.Cells[1].Value = i.ToString();
    dr.Cells[2].Value = item.COMPANY.ToString();
    dr.Cells[3].Value = item.PROVINCE.ToString();
    dr.Cells[4].Value = item.DISTRICT.ToString();
    dr.Cells[5].Value = item.VILLAGE.ToString();
    dr.Cells[6].Value = item.ESTABLISH.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dr.Cells[7].Value = item.TEL.ToString();
    dr.Cells[8].Value = item.MOBILE.ToString();
    dr.Cells[9].Value = item.EMAIL.ToString();
    dr.Cells[10].Value = item.ACC1.ToString();
    dr.Cells[11].Value = item.ACC2.ToString();
    dr.Cells[12].Value = item.STATUSFLAG.ToString();
    dr.Cells[13].Value = item.UPDATEBY.ToString();
    dr.Cells[14].Value = item.LASTUPDATE.ToString();

    grid.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Here is the error message

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index

Detail of error message is here

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index
>
> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)

Actually, I double checked the existign column names in UI grid is 15 and in coding I was declare from 0 to 14. I have no idea.

Please, can anyone suggest how to do this? It is my first Linq project.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Until you add the DataGridRow to the DataGrid, it has no relation to it and thus does not know that you have 15 columns. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497211/add-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: Also: Instead of `i = +1;` you probably mean `i += 1;`

Comment: Thank you sir,
I has already been fix bug you recommended but still throw the same error.

Comment: i += 1;
DataGridViewRow dr = (DataGridViewRow)grid.Rows[0].Clone();

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include new information as this is easily missed when writing it in the comments.

Comment: Is there some reason you do not use the returned collection `qry` from the query as a `DataSource` to the grid? Like… `grid.DataSource = qry` … Adding the rows manually to the grid is only going to create more work for you. Using a `DataSource` for the grid will eliminate the current code.

Comment: I add each value directly into the grid.Rows.Add(1,2,3,4,5,...) -> It's worked for me.

Comment: I don't use grid.DataSource = qry.ToList(); because some unicode character trouble. I has already add into the question description.

Comment: You need to further explain when using `qry` as a `DataSource` is not working for you… you state… _”..but due to some reasons of unicode charater for column HeaderText.”_ … ? Whatever reason the header text is not correct… you can change the header text to anything you want.

Comment: yes, I added more explaining in the description.

Comment: If your experience leans toward adding the row manually to the grid… then have you tried to simply “add” a new row like… `grid.Rows.Add(item.OID.ToString(), i.ToString(), item.COMPANY.ToString(), item.PROVINCE.ToString(),…` …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the row by getting the grids "new" row index and add the `item` properties to that row in the grid... Something like...

```
foreach (MCOMPANY item in qry.ToList()) {
  int newRowIndex = grid.Rows.Add();
  grid.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = item.OID.ToString();
  grid.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[1].Value = i.ToString();
  grid.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = item.COMPANY.ToString();
  grid.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[3].Value = item.PROVINCE.ToString();
  grid.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[4].Value = item.DISTRICT.ToString();
  // ....
}
```

As noted already in the comments… The reason your current code fails starts on the line…

```
DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
```

This creates a “generic” new `DataGridViewRow`, however, it has no columns/cells. Therefore, when the code tries to set the value in column/cell [0] of that row…

```
dr.Cells[0].Value = item.OID.ToString();
```

The index out of bounds exception is thrown for obvious reasons.