# c# winforms datagridview add row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewrow

c# windows forms
i have a datagridview and two columns are present which are created at form design time.
i fetch the data from a table and want to add the data row-wise into the grid.

i could do it in two ways

### 1. for every row in the table

`DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row["EmpId"], row["Name"]);`

### 2. using array - for every row in the table

```
   ArrayList grdrow = new ArrayList();
   grdrow.Add(0);
   grdrow.Add(row["EmpId"].ToString());
   grdrow.Add(row["Name"].ToString());
   DataGridView1.Rows.Add(grdrow.ToArray());
```

i want to add rows into the gridview using DataGridViewRow, but its not working.
code i used is:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DataGridViewRow rowadd = new DataGridViewRow();
    rowadd.CreateCells(DataGridView1); 
    rowadd.Cells["Empid"].Value = row["EmpId"]; // it gives error here Column name 'Empid' cannot be found
    rowadd.Cells["EmpName"].Value = row["Name"];
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: [this can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically/10063825)

Comment: Just set the table as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`: `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Answer (score 1):

The below segment should work for you.

```
//set your count of columns here
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;

// Assign your columns
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "EmpId";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";

// Add your rows here    
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("ValueForColl1", "ValueForColl2");
```

Should do the trick for you the issue, drop me a message if your unsure.

Comment: how this is different from `DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row["EmpId"], row["Name"]);` from question??