# Add a new row to datagrid view and reflect the changes in database

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a dgv which I bind to a datatable.

```
public Form1()
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from workers order by id", connStr);
    cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    dt = new DataTable();
}
```

Here I fill the datatable and link the gridview to the datasource

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

When I want to add a new row to the datagridview I do the following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());

    da.Update(dt);  //reflects changes to database

    dt.Clear();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
}
```

Is there a way to add the row without having to reload the whole table?

Comment: you mean "to add the row" to the UI table?

Comment: ckeck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: yes i mean to the ui

Comment: If I add a row to the user interface (datagridview) directly, then i do not have the id field which is identity field