# Replacing item in ItemsSource, make DataGrid sorting goes mad

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid sorted by user by clicking on headers.
When an item is selected, i must refresh it from the data source.

When I replace the new item in ItemsSource, the row is moving.
The sort must be on a column, all items must have the same value for this column.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"      
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"   
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    DataContext="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=viewModel}">

<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>

</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp4
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                Name = "Foo", Age = 10
            },
             new Person()
            {
                Name = "Bar", Age = 10
            },
            new Person()
            {
                Name = "Yolo", Age = 10
            },
        };
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Persons"));
        }
    }        

    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            SelectedPersonChanged();
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPerson"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void SelectedPersonChanged()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            //Get a refreshed instance of person from DataSource
            //For the purpose of the example, we admit that the values are the same
            Person updatedPerson = new Person() { Age = SelectedPerson.Age, Name = SelectedPerson.Name };

            //Update in collection
            int previousIndex = Persons.IndexOf(SelectedPerson);
            Persons[previousIndex] = updatedPerson;
            _selectedPerson = updatedPerson;               
        }
    }
}

public class Person  
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
}
```

Live example :

[image: Preview]

Any idea how to replace the item without breaking row order ?

Thanks

**Edit**

I ended up using AutoMapper to copy Person from data source to SelectedPerson.

In the ViewModel constructor :

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Person, Person>());            

private void SelectedPersonChanged()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            //Get a refreshed instance of person from DataSource
            //For the purpose of the example, we admit that the values are the same
            Person updatedPerson = new Person()
            {
                Age = SelectedPerson.Age, Name = SelectedPerson.Name
            };

            Mapper.Map(updatedPerson, SelectedPerson);               
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried editing the DataGrid rows [themselfes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically)? It's a little hacky, but maybe it's the way to go (not very MVVMy though)

Comment: Unfortunately, the MVVM constraint can't be crossed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way would be to edit existing instance rather than removing it and adding new one.

Just make Person implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and edit the properties.

```
  private void SelectedPersonChanged()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson != null)
        {
            var personFromDB = GetFromDB(SelectedPerson.Id);

             SelectedPerson.Age = personFromDB.Age;
             SelectedPerson.Name = personFromDB.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah sure in a simple example. But my Model is far more complicated (children collection, reference type etc). I'd like to avoid this solution, if possible

Comment: you can use reflection to copy all properties deeply automatically for every class. The GridView is just doing it's job: reactive to ItemAdded (or even ItemReplaced when I google a bit) event. I don't know how to cheat DataGrid, but my answer will do what you want

Comment: Seems there is not much solution, i ended up using AutoMapper to copy personFromDB into SelectedPerson. I'll edit my question and i'll accept your answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try sorting by more than one field. Would probably work best if your data has an id field or other unique field that doesn't change... otherwise it still may jump around if, for example, Name changed when you reloaded it from the database.

Here is how you could do it with the two fields you listed (Age/Name). When you sort by Age, a secondary sort by Name is added. And when you sort by Name, a secondary sort by Age is added.

xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"
    Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>
```

code:

```
    private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView((sender as DataGrid).ItemsSource);
        v.SortDescriptions.Clear();

        // Set column sort direction - otherwise you won't see the arrow on the column header
        if (!e.Column.SortDirection.HasValue)
            e.Column.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
        e.Column.SortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection.Value == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending;

        // Add sort description
        v.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, e.Column.SortDirection.Value));

        // Add secondary sort description (age or name)
        var secondarySort = e.Column.SortMemberPath == "Age" ? "Name" : "Age";
        v.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(secondarySort, ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        // Add more sort descriptions, as needed.

        // We handled it...
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my DataGrid is a custom control which is generic. I don't know the sort in advance.