# Can the columns of a new row being added to a DataGridView control be referred to by name..?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating a Windows Forms 2.0 app in Visual Studio 2008. The form has a DataGridView control which will have rows programmatically added to it with the overload `Add(ByVal ParamArray Values())`, as shown:

```
dgv.Rows.Add (var1, var2, var3, varEtc)
```

Is there a way to refer to the cells *by name* rather than by relying on their *order*..**?**

The dgv will have many columns, and referring to them by order will be confusing as I develop the app. It would be much easier to refer to them by some name or index string.

Unfortunately the DataGridView classes are many and vast, and I don't know which direction to go in. I have a half-baked idea to create each row object first, configure it, and and then add it to the collection, as shown below:

```
Dim dgvr as DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow
...more code needed...
dgvr.SomeProp.ID    = var1
dgvr.SomeProp.NameF = var2
dgvr.SomeProp.NameL = var3
dgvr.SomeProp.Etc   = varEtc
dgv.Rows.Add (dgvr)
```

I'm sure this isn't the only way, and not yet even a functional one. Can I make this work..**?** What other ways are there..**?** Anything better..**?**

Comment: When adding columns, assign `Name` property of the columns. Then refer the cells by column name, for example `dgvr.Cells["FirstName"].Value = "John";` Also in general consider using data binding to a `BindngList<T>` or a `DataTable`. It make data manipulation and data display much easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically?rq=1 May help

Comment: Thanks. Mick's link pointed me on the trail to getting what I was hoping for. I'll add my own answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically?rq=1) in the comment from Mick on
my OP set me on the road to what I was hoping for - which turned out to be a few steps beyond what I originally conceived.

What I ended up with was a class extension of `DataGridViewRow`. It adds a the new extension function `GetCellByColumnCaption`, which does exactly that: it returns a `DataGridViewCell` object corresponding to the caption of the cell's column in the `DataGridView` control.

Doing it this way removes the control names from being an issue. Now I can simply refer to the cells in new rows by the most visible identifier they have: the column header text.

Here's a working example...

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load( _
                        ByVal sender As Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
                        ) _
                        Handles Me.Load

        'Remove the new blank row.
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click( _
                        ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
                        ) _
                        Handles Button1.Click

        Dim newRowIdx As Integer = dgv.Rows.Add()
        Dim newRowObj As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows.Item(newRowIdx)
        newRowObj.GetCellByColumnCaption("ID").Value = "123"
        newRowObj.GetCellByColumnCaption("Name").Value = "Bob"
        newRowObj.GetCellByColumnCaption("Etc").Value = "Red"

    End Sub

End Class

Module ClassExtensions
    'Note: The Extension() attribute requires .Net 3.5 or above. 
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Friend Function GetCellByColumnCaption( _
                        ByVal dgvr As DataGridViewRow, _
                        ByVal colCaption As String _
                        ) _
                        As DataGridViewCell

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dgvr.Cells
            Dim hdrText = LCase(cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText)
            colCaption = LCase(colCaption)
            If hdrText = colCaption Then
                GetCellByColumnCaption = cell
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        GetCellByColumnCaption = Nothing
    End Function

End Module
```