# Form fields to populate gridview without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I need to build a function to dynamically add rows to a gridview from form objects such as dropdowns and text fields.
I need to do this without touching a database.
And I need to give the user the ability to add multiple rows one at a time.
This is what I have come up with so far.
I get a null reference on the if

```
    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Field");
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");
    }

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Field"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    dr["Value"] = TextBox2.Text.Trim();

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Comment: Do you plan to run this code once only, or once per new row?

Comment: The user would fill in a dropdown and text box.   Those values need to be added to the gridview.   I am trying to use a datatable to move the info from the form objects to the gridview.   The issue I am running into now is the form just replaces instead of  adding a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

is doing, but it's assigning null to `dt` (because `GridView1.DataSource` is null)

Try:

```
var dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
if (dt == null) 
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

In future, when you get a null reference error, add a breakpoint and check the value of each variable in the row to see which one is null.

Comment: I disagree. I think he is trying to grab the current data source from the gridview, add a new row to that variable, then rebind it. This is correct, just needs to initialize it if it comes back null

Comment: @dvo - maybe, but appears to be null, and he initialised `dt` in the previous line. I'll edit my answer to handle both.

Comment: Yes, he is still missing that. I just think setting the data source where you are suggesting is incorrect.

Comment: @dvo - good point, setting the data source should only be done once, while adding rows might be done multiple times.

Comment: Correct - I believe OP is looking for the ability to add one row at a time. I think you've solved his NULL Reference exception with this answer.

Comment: Thank....   this is helping.  @dvo   you are correct..  I am letting the user build a list of items from a text field and dropdown.   I will admit, I am not the best when working with data tables.   So I made the changes..   No Errors now.
However..  The new data is replacing the old data instead of adding to it.

` 
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
`

Comment: Gene - you need to separate the creation of the data table from the code that adds rows. We're struggling because we've only got one function.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `ViewState` variable instead of pulling the data source. There may be weird things with the rows...

**Set** view state with `.DataBind()`: `ViewState["GV1_DT"] = dt;`

**Pull** it with `var dt = ViewState["GV1_DT"] as DataTable;` Then you can incorporate your null check by doing: `var dt = (ViewState["GV1_DT"] as DataTable) ?? new DataTable();`

**Full code:**

```
    var dt = (ViewState["GV1_DT"] as DataTable) ?? new DataTable(); // -- PULL

    if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Field");
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");
    }

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Field"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    dr["Value"] = TextBox2.Text.Trim();

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ViewState["GV1_DT"] = dt;    // -- SET
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```