# Reserving (pre-allocating) rows of DataGridView

Tags: c#, dataview

I'm loading rows from a file into a `DataGridView`.  The file has 25000 rows.

The loading takes enough time that I added a progress bar to the GUI (updating every 128 rows).

Is there a method or process to reserve rows before I start using the `Add` method?

I'd like to speed up the adding of data rows.

**Environment:**
C# -- Visual Studio 2017
Windows 10

*P.S.* All my searches are about adding a single row to the `DataGridView`.  I didn't find anything about pre-allocating or reserving space.

*For those needing a sample code*

```
String[] items = file.Split(',');
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DataGridView data_table;
foreach (String item in items)
    list.Add(item.Trim());
for (int i = 0; i < list.count; ++i)
{
    string time_interval_as_string = list[i];
    uint   time_interval = 0;
    uint.TryParse(time_interval_as_string, out time_interval);
    string energy_value_as_string = list[++i];  
    double energy_value = 0.0;
    double.TryParse(energy_value_as_string, out energy_value);  

    dataTable.Rows.Add(time_interval, energy_value);

}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `DataViewGrid` in WinForms or WPF - don't you mean `DataGridView` instead?

Comment: Use AddRange instead.  Add is repainting the control after each item making it very slow.

Comment: @jdweng `DataGridView` doesn't repaint on every `Add`: it only repaints rows visible in the control's viewport _and_ only in response to a `WM_PAINT` message after invalidation (which never happens inside user-code unless they call `DoEvents`), so calling `Add` twice will only invalidate the control _once_ and then repaint _once_. But I do agree that `DataGridView` does have poor performance by default though.

Comment: Please show [how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10063770/1997232) you add rows and provide more background. Are you trying to implement [virtual mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control)?

Comment: Populate a DataTable or some other list and assign that to the DataSource property of the grid.

Comment: @Dai : Are you sure???As you add rows the data is going to scroll and rows in view are going to change.  When do the rows get validated?

Comment: IMHO, the repainting or refreshing is not the delay factor.  The table is not refreshed until after all items are loaded into the table.